# error - Unexpected token in Vue component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am just starting out with Vue and am getting a stubborn error on a simple component. First, this is the error.

`Syntax Error: SyntaxError: C:...src\components\Stats.vue: Unexpected token (20:2)`

and **line 20:**

```
18 |       newLink: '',
  19 |     },
> 20 |   },
     |   ^
  21 |   computed: {
  22 |     ...mapGetters([
  23 |       'countLinks',
```

Here is the code:

```
<script>
import { mapGetters, mapMutations } from 'vuex'

export default {
  name: 'Stats',
  data() {
    return {
      newLink: '',
    },
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters([
      'countLinks',
    ]),
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapMutations([
      'ADD_LINK',
    ]),
    addLink: function () {
      this.ADD_LINK(this.newLink)
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

As you can see, the error references line 20 just before `computed`. But both the curly bracket and the comma are needed so I am not sure what can be done to fix it. There doesn't seem to be anywhere that a semicolon can be placed like the error is suggesting.

I have also tried adding commas wherever possible as the code was previously complaining about missing commas. However, this hasn't solved the problem either. I have looked around for solutions but haven't found anything that works.

---

Just to update, this error persists even with trying an arrow function:

```
data: ()  => ({
    newLink: '',
}),
```

Using `function` keyword like so:

```
data: function () {
  return {
    newLink: '',
  }
}
```

Or omitting `function` and using only `data` as the function itself like so:

```
 data()  {
    return {
      newLink: '',
    }
  },
```

Each one of these options returns either an `unexpected token` or `semicolon` error. I have tried practically every solution I can find, scoured the web, and read the docs without finding anything that works.

Answer (score 2):

Here's your code and its problems

```js
import { mapGetters, mapMutations } from 'vuex'

export default {
  name: 'Stats',
  data() {
    return {
      newLink: '', //  unnecessary comma, syntactically ok
    }, //  unnecessary comma, causes an error
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters([ //  no need for `...` here
      'countLinks', //  unnecessary comma, syntactically ok
    ]), //  unnecessary comma, syntactically ok
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapMutations([
      'ADD_LINK', //  unnecessary comma, syntactically ok
    ]),
    addLink: function () {
      this.ADD_LINK(this.newLink)
    }, //  unnecessary comma, syntactically ok
  }, //  unnecessary comma, syntactically ok
};
```

The one main issue is this one

```js
data() {
  return {
    newLink: '',
  }, //  this one right here
}
```

The `return` is trying to evaluate the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) expression and return the last operand. The issue is, there is no last operand.

Here's your code with the error fixed and all unnecessary elements removed

```js
import { mapGetters, mapMutations } from 'vuex'

export default {
  name: 'Stats',
  data () {
    return {
      newLink: ""
    }
  },
  computed: mapGetters(["countLinks"]),
  methods: {
    ...mapMutations(["ADD_LINK"]),
    addLink () {
      this.ADD_LINK(this.newLink)
    }
  }
}
```

Your `data` function could also be written as

```js
data: () => ({ newLink: "" }),
```

but that's really just down to personal preference.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive response.I tried the changes and it still didn't fix it. After looking into it deeper it turned out that `eslint` was causing the errors. Finally rid of them by running `npm uninstall` for every `eslint` related package in the `package.json` file.

Comment: @mikeym eslint is typically very helpful. I wouldn't recommend uninstalling it

Comment: I understand it is helpful to make us produce better-formatted code but it was causing so many headaches in a small practice app. The syntax errors it was finding seemed to be completely unfixable no matter what I added or removed. Is there some way of quickly resolving eslint syntax problems?

Comment: @mikeym typically, you just fix them. If you showed some examples that you didn't understand how to fix, I'm sure we could help

Comment: Thanks for the help @Phil. Since I removed the eslint packages I no longer has access to the specific errors but I guess my problem was even after following the suggestions of the linter the errors persisted and/or increased. Making eslint happy can be difficult, especially when using auto-formatting such as Prettier. I will reinstall it later though and try to get a better handle on it.

Answer (score 1):

`data` must be a function ([doc](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#data-Must-Be-a-Function)), the problem is with your typo

Should be this instead

```
data: function () {
  return {
    newLink: '',
  }
}
```

Demo

[image: Edit solitary-leftpad-o21dt]

Comment: Thanks for your response. I already tried `data: function() {...}` but still get the same error.

Comment: @mikeym remove the comma after return also

Comment: ..still doesn't work, unfortunately. I think I have tried every combination of comma addition and removal.

Comment: @mikeym attached a [codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/solitary-leftpad-o21dt), please check

Comment: @hgb123 FYI, OP's `data` already **is** a function. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions

Comment: @Phil That's what I thought. In any case, it still throws an error either way.

Answer (score -1):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/63985603/11022585

or using arrow function.

```
data: ()  => ({
    newLink: '',
}),
```